# aix : To get lines before and after string

Tags: unix, aix

I am using AIX and I have a string "There is no process to read data written to a pipe". I want to get the output 2 lines before and 4 lines after this string. 
The string is present like more than 100 times in the log and I want to output, the last result in the log with this string

I tried using :

```
nawk 'c-->0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=2   a=4 s="There is no process to read data written to a pipe" File.log
```

The output from this command is that I am getting all the 100 plus results where the above string is present

The -A number -B number command is not working in AIX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU grep available, you can use it instead of awk:

```
grep -B 2 -A 4 "There is no process to read data written to a pipe" File.log
```

Comment: The GNU grep is not available

Comment: Thx for the answer: | tail -number